# How to define a UserControl in Python for WPF?

Tags: python, .net, wpf, xaml, python.net

I'm new to `pythonnet` and am wondering if it is possible to define a `UserControl` in `pythonnet` with WPF? Since it's impossible to including all `xaml` code in one file, I have to split it into pieces for better project structure management.

In C#, I need to implement a class partially for `UserControl`, but how could I achieve that in Python? And how to use that `UserControl` in another `xaml` file? Should I define `__namespace__` to use it in another place?

Thanks a lot!